# MSBuild fails from command Line but succeeds from visual studio cmd line

Tags: c#, msbuild

I am unable to build a vs15 project through MSBuild command from cmd line but through vs17 cmd line I can ?Can someone tell me why this behaviour.I am getting error :
**msbuild** : error msb1008: only one project can be specified
when building through Msbuild.exe located at c:\program files (x86)\msbuild 
and a different errror:
MSBuild.Community.Tasks.XmlRead task could not be loaded from the assembly
The "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.XmlRead" task could not be loaded from the assembly
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\Statlant_DNN_Module\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.4.0.128\tools\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll.
Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\Statlant_DNN_Module\packages\MSBuildTasks.1.4.0.128\tools\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll'
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are
available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Am I missing something, or have I done something incorrectly?

Comment: The VS command line sets up the environment variables to point to all of the required dependency locations. The standard command line does not.

Answer (score 1):

MSBuild makes use of many command-line options and environment variables that have to be defined. Fortunately, Visual Studio creates a shortcut named Developer Command Prompt that does all this; you can find it in the Visual Studio folder in your Start menu.

Read more in [Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs).

Comment: can u please tell how can I build the solution using CMD line , because I am implementing continuous integration through Jenkins , so I need to build the solution using Windows Batch Command.

Comment: You can run the corresponding .bat files described in [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-170#developer_command_file_locations)